# How can I store an image in a database using Ruby and Sequel?

Tags: ruby, image, blob, sequel, ramaze

I am using Ruby, or more specifically the [Ramaze](http://ramaze.net) framework with the [Sequel ORM](http://sequel.rubyforge.org/). So please don't tell me about the [Paperclip](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip) gem, as it is only compatible with ActiveRecord.

With that in mind, how can I store an image in a database using Ruby and Sequel?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
require "sequel"

DB = Sequel.sqlite

DB.create_table :images do
  primary_key :id
  String :name
  File :data
end

images = DB[:images]
images.insert(name: 'foo', data: Sequel.blob(File.read('/mydir/myimage.jpg')))
```

Comment: In most cases, you'll want to use `data: Sequel.blob(File.read('/mydir/myimage.jpg'))`.  Maybe it doesn't matter on SQLite, but it will on other databases.

Comment: The `Sequel.blob` does also matter with SQLite. I just received a `SQLite3::SQLException: unrecognized token`-error when I used `File.read` without `Sequel.blob` (it depends on the file content. Some files worked, other files dumped).